# How to move mobile robot in rviz

Tags: rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am sorry for being naive.
I have GPS sensor information from a moving car. I have URDF model of a robot with four wheels. All joints are fixed (wheel to base_link). I want to move the robot in rviz according to GPS data. I am able to broadcast tf trasnform following this :[Link](https://answers.ros.org/question/199079/problem-moving-the-robot-in-rviz/)

I have gone through these tutorials but all using joint_state_publisher. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274377/how-to-move-mobile-robot-in-rviz/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2017-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-28**:
Maybe [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/274332/steps-how-to-start-with-navigation-stack/) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer.

In this case, no moving joint is needed. We just need tf trasnform from base_link to fixed frame (odom). Just broadcast tf transform and set the header frame id to base_link.

---

Originally posted by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) with karma: 377 on 2017-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0